# Escape key on opened modal triggers only once

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bootbox

I'm dealing with annoying bug, I have simmple bootstrap modal with two inputs, and small bootbox dialog which opens on cancel button on modal, x, or esc, the trouble is, I can only open bootbox dialog on top modal via ESC key once, bootbox dialog closes and ESC key doesn't work...

```
    <div id="editHoliday" class="fade modal inmodal" tabindex="-1" data- keyboard="false">
<form id="editHoliday_form" class="vm-model-sec">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button close holidayEditCancel" aria-label='Close dialog'><span>&times;</span></button>
                <h1 class="modal-title h4" style="text-align: center;">Edit - Holiday</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="holidayNameEdit" class="vm-holidayname-label">Holiday Name</label>
                        <input id="holidayNameEdit" name="holidayName" type="text" class="form-control required" maxlength="32">
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <input id="holidayIdEdit" name="holidayId" type="hidden" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="holidayEditCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-white holidayEditCancel">Cancel</button>
                <button id="holidayEditSave" data-style="expand-right" class="btn btn-primary "><span>Save</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in my .js file, bootbox dialog

```
function CancelSaveHoliday() {
bootbox.dialog({
    backdrop: true,
    closeButton: true,
    show: false,
    title: "Something",
    message: "Would you like to save?,
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: "CANCEL",
            className: "",
            callback: function () {
            }
        },
        danger: {
            label: "NO",
            className: "",
            callback: function () {
                $("#editHoliday").modal("hide");
            }
        },
        main: {
            label: "YES",
            className: "btn-primary",
            callback: function () {
                $("#holidayEditSave").click();

            }
        }
    }
}).on("show.bs.modal", function () {
}).on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    renewParentModal($(this), $("#editHoliday_form"), e);
}).modal('show');
```

}

My goal is to when I press Cancel on bootbox dialog, i am able to press again ESC key and open bootbox dialog again, but only works if i manually click somewhere and then ESC key works...

```
 $("#editHoliday").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 27) {
        //opens cancel dialog
    }

  });
```

Can someone explain me why ESC key works only once, but doesn't always why my modal is opened? How can I fix that?

Comment: Try using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/): `$(document).on('keyup', '#editHoliday', function (e) { ... });` - I'm suspecting there's some sort of DOM manipulation that bootbox is doing that is potentially cloning / destroying  etc. that modal.

Comment: This is (at the moment) by design (see https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/512) - the assumption is that you create a new Bootbox modal each time you need to display it.